# Access 2013 Return UserID Once

Tags: concatenation, ms-access-2013

I have a database where a userID exists multiple times in a table, data structure is like so

```
userid   event      rank
mm11     hurdles    first
mm11     sock       fourth
mm11     three      fifteen
rr99     run        seven
rr99     swim       second
```

In access, I want to return only one row per userID and it does not matter how the event data is parsed.  I tried to `concatenate` the event data but my query still returns an individual row for each userid.

This is the SQL from my access query - what should I change so that I only have one row per userID returned?

```
Select userID, [event] & ", " & [rank] As [TestConcat]
From eventdata
Group by userID;
```

**EDIT**
My desired returned results are like this

a`userid    eventInfo
  mm11      hurdles, first, sock, fourth, three, fifteen
  rr99      run, seven, swim, second`

Answer (score -1):

Do you need anything other than the userID?  If not what is below will return the userIDs you are after.

```
SELECT userID
FROM eventdata
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY userID;
```

Comment: Yes I need to combine the event data to one line for each userID. Editing my OP now to better explain.  And it does not have to be a comma seperated list, any seperator will do